# How do i evenly space out hyperlink text vertically in html?

Tags: html, css

So I'm creating a footer for my web document and I'm trying to achieve the following i drafted in word:

[image]

Home, Legal, Location and Contact are hyperlinks as seen in many website footers, and they are evenly spaced out vertically.

I'm having **issue getting them to evenly space out** in my html document. I tried using "margin-top" property but the Home hyperlink would then have uneven spacing at the top.

Would appreciate some help on this.

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#wrapper {
    border: 1px solid orange;
    height: 300px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

#content {
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/test_style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="content">
            <a href="#">Home</a>
            <a href="#">Legal</a>
            <a href="#">Location</a>
            <a href="#">Contact</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried justify-content: space-around; ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be totally even spacing implementation for your use-case :-

(Currently I had to make `width` and `height` to be `100%` since you have an explicit `border` on them and it wouldn't look good but without `border`, you can just use `height:100%` and it should work the same )

Also you can use `space-around` as well for `justify-content` which will decrease the top and bottom margin for your links.

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#wrapper {
    border: 1px solid orange;
    height: 300px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

#content {
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    align-items:center;
    justify-content:space-evenly;
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/test_style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="content">
            <a href="#">Home</a>
            <a href="#">Legal</a>
            <a href="#">Location</a>
            <a href="#">Contact</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you very much! justify-content: space evenly did the trick!